# How to use code blocks to assign values using syntax: value = (bool) ? opt1 : opt2; in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to assign a value using the syntax like this:

```
id value = (someBool) ? option1 : option2;
```

But I'd like to assign using code blocks like so:

```
id someObject = (someBool) ? {
    id firstOption;
    // do some stuff

    firstOption;
} : {
    id secondOption;
    // do some stuff

    secondOption;
};
```

For clarity, this is equivalent to:

```
id someObject;

if (someBool) {
    id firstOption;
    // do some stuff

    someObject = firstOption;
} 
else {
    id secondOption;
    // do some stuff

    someObject = secondOption;
};
```

I read an article about assigning values this way, and I thought I could use it like this, but I can't seem to find the article and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Thanks!

#### Question

1. Is this possible?
2. if (answerTo1 == YES) answerHow();

Comment: Do you want to assign a value or a block reference?

Comment: @DovD. -- Assign a value

Comment: short-hand if/else syntax is intended for just that: when writing out full if/else statements is cumbersome or hurts readability. What's your aversion to just writing it out if{}else{} ?

Comment: @remus -- no aversion, just wanted to try it.

Comment: Ahh ok gotcha. I usually find that when reviewing code that uses shorthand in an extended block format like that ends up quite hard to read; so just keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes. It is called a ["compound statement expressions"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which is a GCC extension to the C language (and 
understood by Clang as well).

> if (answerTo1 == YES) answerHow();

You have to put parentheses around the `{...}` block:

```
id someObject = (someBool) ? ({
    id firstOption;
    // do some stuff

    firstOption;
}) : ({
    id secondOption;
    // do some stuff

    secondOption;
});
```

Comment: One should add that this is not valid in C++ and ANSI/ISO C and only supported by GCC (and possibly clang). It seems, GCC itself somewhat discourages its usage.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: You are right, I have updated the answer accordingly, thanks for the feedback.